# I need to update the field Last_Login__c in User with the value of the field LastLoginDate

Tags: apex, trigger

This code works in the developer console but the trigger does not fire.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
trigger LastLoginUpdate on User (after update) {

    User[] myUsers = [SELECT LastLoginDate from User];
        for(User i:myUsers){

    i.Last_Login__c=i.LastLoginDate;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not working with the data in the trigger context (`trigger.new`), you queried your own user data. Because you queried your own data, you need to `update` those records to see any changes in the database. Try instead using the data provided by the trigger, ie, `trigger.new` and `trigger.old`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

In `After event` we need to perform the DML Operation to update records. But you are updating same record, Thus to avoid extra DML operation & recrusion process, we can update same record in `Before event`.

`Before event` doesn't require any DML operation to perform.

No need to write SOQL query. `trigger.new` returns a list of the new versions of the sObject records

So, Your trigger will be like this.

```
trigger LastLoginUpdate on User (before update) {

    for(User i:trigger.new){
        i.Last_Login__c=i.LastLoginDate;
    }
}
```

---

Solution 2 :

You can also create the `Last_Login__c` as a Formula field to update the field instead of writting code.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is copying an OOTB field to a custom field

```
trigger LastLoginUpdate on User (before update) {
    // all fields on User, including formula fields are part of Trigger.new context
    for (User u: Trigger.new)
         u.Last_Login__c = u.LastLogin;

    // trigger.new implicitly updates the object in 
    // before insert/update triggers when trigger reaches last statement

}
```

Comment: I have tried to above and it does not update Last_Login__c. I think the problem is the difficulty in capturing the information in LastLoginDate. This field is not available as a standard field in salesforce and it cannot be referred to in any workflow rule.

Comment: @LibradaCespedoda -- what version is your trigger running at?  The field is on the User object